# How to display my MacBook desktop on a TV through Apple TV

Tags: macbook, appletv, airplay

I just bought the 2<sup>nd</sup> generation Apple TV.

I need to know if there's a way so that I can airplay my whole desktop (I have a MacBook) onto my TV through the Apple TV, relaying both sound and video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erica Sadun's "Bruce" tool is the only solution available to you:

http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/

Hopefully Apple will add this feature natively to OS X as they have done for iOS.